# $n + (n+1)^2 + (n+2)^3$ is a multiple of $16$ where $n$ is odd number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$n + (n+1)^2 + (n+2)^3 $

is a multiple of $16$

where $n$ is odd number

And how do i prove it.
And i tried to do with expanding but could not figured it out.
I have attached an image[image]

Comment: Do you know the congruence modulo?

Comment: $n$ is odd, so now write $n=2r+1$ for some $r$.

Comment: no, I dont know `congruence modulo`

Comment: You did a great job expanding the number. Now, simply write $n$ as $2r+1$ since $n$ is odd.

Comment: even my expanding the formula is wrong, well i got the solution thanks again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $n=2k+1$, since it is an odd integer.

Now expand to get:
$$2k+1+(2k+2)^2+(2k+3)^3=8(k+1)(k+2)^2$$ but $(k+1)(k+2)$ is divisible by 2, since one of $k+1,k+2$ is even. Therefore the whole expression is divisible by 16.

Comment: how did we got `8(k+1)(k+2)^2` and i got the final answers as `8k^3 + 40k^2 + 64k + 32`

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

Setting $n=2m+1,$

We get  $$8m^3+40m^2+64m+32=8m^2(m-1)+48m^2+64m+32$$

Now, $\displaystyle m^2(m-1)$ is divisible by $\displaystyle m(m-1)$ which being product of two consecutive integers is even